# Function Variable isn't being written to by tkinter combobox

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on an application that will log events regarding a particular type of service work.

The application uses a SQLite Database that I'd like to populate with 'events' in the form of Database items.

My Issue is that the ComboBox's '.get()' doesn't get written to the list of data to be databased.

I'm currently at PageTwo, gradually adding functionality to the pages as I go on.

Please could someone show me where I've gone wrong?

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self,text='New Work',font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button3 = ttk.Button(self,text='Home',command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button3.pack()

        sel = StringVar()
        sel2 = StringVar()

        l1=Label(self,text='Work Type: ')
        l1.pack()

        combo1 = ttk.Combobox(self, width=20,   height=40,textvariable=sel)
        combo1.pack()
        combo1['values'] = combo_values_input('Work_Dev.db','TypeData','WorkType')


        l2=Label(self,text='Customer: ')
        l2.pack()

        combo2 = ttk.Combobox(self, width=20,   height=40,textvariable=sel2)
        combo2.pack()
        combo2['values'] = combo_values_input('Work_Dev.db','SiteData','Site')

        #datalist = [str(combo1.get()),'data02',f'{date_time}','data04']
        datalist = []

        b1=ttk.Button(self,text="Save to DataBase",command=db_func)
        b1.pack()

        sel.trace('w',myupd)
        sel2.trace('w',myupd2)
```

Comment: Please ask me for the rest of the code. It works and runs a tkinter window, but StackOverflow says I have an indentation problem. So I can send it seperately.

Comment: please provide a [mre], currently your code doesn't even contain the method `get` anywhere, it also is not `PageTwo` which you seem to have questions about, either how, but you need to provide a [mre] (and read carefully how to create it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to define the database function within the page I want to use it in for the ComboBox.

Comment: You can thank users in comments. Use the answer section for posting a known, working solution.

Comment: Thank you Matiiss, for taking the time to look at this.